# c++ - Is it possible to declare a copy constructor in a derived class that references another derived class?

Tags: c++

For example, if I create a `Base` class and 2 derived classes, `DerivedOne` and `DerivedTwo`, is it possible to declare a copy constructor in `DerivedOne` that references `DerivedTwo`?

Thanks

Comment: So is the idea that a `DerivedTwo` could be copied to a `DerivedOne`?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Long answer: Yes, and you need to either forward-declare `DerivedTwo`, or define it before the definition of `DerivedOne`.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `DerivedOne(const DerivedTwo& other)`?

Comment: You may pass "anything" to a constructor (siblings in derivation tree included) but a [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is specifically a constructor which copies from (another) instance of same class: _A copy constructor of class T is a non-template constructor whose first parameter is T&‍, const T&‍, volatile T&‍, or const volatile T&‍, and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the parameters all have default values._

Comment: @Scheff So, the answer is: Yes, but it will be a "normal" constructor, not a copy-constructor? (Bonus question: Is there any difference other than the name?)

Comment: @Frodyne According to linked doc.: _The copy constructor is called whenever an object is initialized (by direct-initialization or copy-initialization) from another object of the same type (unless overload resolution selects a better match or the call is elided)_ So, it's somehow special.

Comment: @Frodyne I made the following contrived sample for a constructor with argument _T&_ while the copy-constructor is deleted: [Sample on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa06bdc80ffb2ad0). To enable unintended use of copy-constructor, change the `#if 0` to `#if 1`.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you. It was just an idle question, and I was not expecting that much of an answer, so much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B{
    protected:
        int a;
    public:
        B(int i):a(i){}
        B(const B &b): a(b.a){cout<<"copying... ";}   //base class copy constructor
        virtual void print()=0;
};

class D1: public B{
    //other functions and variables
    public:
        D1(): B(5){ /*other initializations*/ };
        void print(){cout<<"D1:"<<a<<endl;}
};

class D2: public B{
    //other functions and variables
    public:
        D2(const B &b):B(b){ /*other initializations*/ }    //COPY CONSTRUCTOR
        void print(){cout<<"D2:"<<a<<endl;}
};

int main() {
    D1 d1;
    d1.print();     // output: D1:5

    B &b=d1;
    D2 d2(b);
    d2.print();     // output: copying... D2:5

    return 0;
}
```

Tell me in comment if something is not clear.